# How many times a package will be imported when imported inside a function in Scala

Tags: scala, import

I've below function code snippet in **Scala**:

```
def sqrtplus1(x: Int) = {
  import scala.math.sqrt
  sqrt(x) + 1.0
}
```

And I'm making following 3 calls to the above function:

```
sqrtplus1(5) // outputs 26
sqrtplus1(6) // outputs 37
sqrtplus1(7) // outputs 50
```

While the above works fine,

However, I'd like to know, how many times the package `scala.math.sqrt` will be imported when `sqrtplus1` function is called `3` times? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This answer is by @Rob Norris @tpolecat from scala/center (community):

All importing does is let you refer to symbols without a prefix. To the extent that it "happens" at all it's entirely at compile time. **Import statements have no runtime representation**.

(Unlike Python, for example, where importing is a statement that can cause things to happen.)